# Preconditions for stacking

Tags: seismic

Some of the requisite for stacking is that the noise and amplitudes need to be uncorrelated. Can someone explain to me why?

Also is there a drawback for stacking?

Comment: It would help very much if you described what you mean by "stacking". This word is highly overloaded, even within the context of the Earth sciences.

Comment: If you take one measurement of signal S plus random (!) noise N_0, the signal may be dominated by the noise. But if you take the average of two measurements, with a different noise the second time, you get (S+S+N_0+N_1)/2= S + N_0/2 + N_1/2. Crucially, the signal remains while the noise gets suppressed, assuming the noise is different in each measurement. In stacking, the idea is that all coherent information (the 'S' in this example) remains, while the noise ('N_0', 'N_1', ...) is suppressed. See Fig. 3 here http://www.industrial-electronics.com/ew_1971-05_avg.html for example.